# How to access data in another spring bean using current spring bean

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am new to Spring and I have a small requirement.

```
<bean name="triangle" class="com.thomson.learn.spring.triangle">
    <property name="name" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="name" value="easy" />
</bean>
```

I have written beans as shown above. I need to access the value `easy` from the bean with `id="triangle"`, but when I try doing this I get a exception. Can someone please suggest how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.thomson.learn.spring.shape' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'name'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.thomson.learn.spring.shape] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'name': no matching editors or conversion strategy found I get this error when i try doing this can u please help me to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<bean name="triangle" class="com.thomson.learn.spring.triangle">
        <property name="name" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.thomson.learn.spring.shape">
    <property name="name" value="easy" />
</bean>
```

where `com.thomson.learn.spring.triangle` and `com.thomson.learn.spring.shape` must exist as classes in your project. your `String` class bean couldn't have worked because `String` has no `name` property (`getName()` method getter) to access.

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.thomson.learn.spring.shape' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'name'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.thomson.learn.spring.shape] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'name': no matching editors or conversion strategy found 

I get this error when i try doing this can u please help me to resolve it?

Comment: First of all create class `com.thomson.learn.spring.shape`, then create a field `name` in the class.

Answer (score 0):

A String does not have a property 'name', so you can't instantiate one the way you are trying to. Moreover, you don't need to, as you can use it directly as the value, e.g.:

```
<bean name="triangle" class="com.thomson.learn.spring.triangle">
  <property name="name" value="easy" />
</bean>
```

Edit in reply to your comment:
If "name" is of type `shape`, then you need to inject a `shape` here...

```
<bean name="triangle" class="com.thomson.learn.spring.triangle">
  <property name="name" ref="shape" />
</bean>
<bean name="shape" class="com.thomson.learn.spring.shape">
    <!-- configure properties here -->
</bean>
```

The objects wired by Spring are supposed to be JavaBeans. What this means in practice is that they have a no-argument constructor and a set of properties, each of which has both a getter and a setter. When you write a definition such as above, Spring uses the setters to set properties you defined in the configuration file.

For instance if `Shape` was a class as such:

```
package com.thomson.learn.spring.Shape;

class Shape {

  private String name;

  public Shape() {
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Then you could wire it with the following:

```
<bean id="myShape" class="com.thomson.learn.spring.Shape">
  <property name="name" value="blah" />
</bean>
```

Which really translates to Spring executing the following at runtime:

```
Shape myShape = new Shape();
shape.setName("blah");
```

That's all there is to it, except that properties can also be more complex instances of other classes of course, which is why you can use `ref` to refer to another bean for a property.

P.S.: Spring can use reflection to inject values in many cases, so it doesn't actually need a setter, but most people implement their beans this way for various reasons.

Comment: I dont wanna do it directly right i have a requirement which doesn't just say triangle there are 100's of inputs and depending on the bean asked i want to refer to different beans

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.thomson.learn.spring.shape' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'name'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.thomson.learn.spring.shape] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'name': no matching editors or conversion strategy found I get this error when i try doing this can u please help me to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

If it is going to be String(s) that you want to inject into all of your beans you can refer properties from a property file and use `<context:property-placeholder location="location to .properties"/>` 
or you can define properties in the configuration xml with `<util:properties />`

Example for property-placeholder

```
<bean id="appDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/> // Refered from property file
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>
```